# ValueError: shapes (64,28,28) and (784,50) not aligned: 28 (dim 2) != 784 (dim 0)

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I am trying to create my first neural network. I would like from my neural network to predict which number is on the 28x28 input (I am using the MNIST database). The database is imported via Tensorflow.

Shape of my x_test is 10000, 28, 28. The 10000 denotes the number of inputs and 28x28 the height and width.

My error is this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-a6dbf7a3d2aa> in <module>
      1 layer_dims = [784, 50, 20, 10]
----> 2 parameters = model(x_test , y_test, layer_dims)

<ipython-input-35-e0593be872fa> in model(X, Y, layers_dims, optimizer, learning_rate, mini_batch_size, mainActiv, lastActiv, num_epochs, beta, beta1, beta2, epsilon)
     28         for minibatch in minibatches:
     29             (minibatch_X, minibatch_Y) = minibatch
---> 30             a3, cache = forward_propagation(minibatch_X, minibatch_Y, parameters)
     31             cost = compute_cost(a3, minibatch_Y)
     32             grads = L_model_backward(a3, Y, caches, mainActiv)

<ipython-input-15-fc8fba0d23d7> in forward_propagation(X, Y, parameters)
      7         A_prev = A
      8         print("A shape = " + str(A.shape))
----> 9         A, cache = lin_activ_forward(A_prev, parameters["W" + str(l)], parameters["b" + str(l)], activation = "relu")
     10         caches.append(cache)
     11     AL, cache = lin_activ_forward(A, parameters["W" + str(L)], parameters["b" + str(L)], activation = "sigmoid")

<ipython-input-14-760f9d3070ba> in lin_activ_forward(A_prev, W, b, activation)
      9         print("activ b" + str(b.shape))
     10 
---> 11         Z, lin_cache = lin_feedforward(A_prev, W, b)
     12         print("activ Z" + str(Z.shape))
     13         A, activ_cache = relu(Z)

<ipython-input-54-9a032d2cf624> in lin_feedforward(A_prev, W, b)
      1 def lin_feedforward(A_prev, W, b):
      2     #A_prev - aktivace z předchozích vrstev
----> 3     Z = np.dot(A_prev,W) +b #maybe multiply here???
      4     assert(Z.shape == (W.shape[0], A_prev.shape[1]))
      5     print("W1 shape" + str(W1.shape))

ValueError: shapes (64,28,28) and (784,50) not aligned: 28 (dim 2) != 784 (dim 0)
```

I suppose that the main error comes from the np.dot multiplication itself, because I do have my variables in wrong shapes. The point is that I don't get how to fix this? I have learned, that the input layer should be 784 inputs (28x28 - for each pixel), right? How can I use dot product on 3 dimensional matrix and 2 dimensional matrix? I know something small about broadcasting, but I can't to find a solution to this

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Without seeing your code I can't be sure, but you probably just need to reshape your inputs like `x_test = x_test.reshape(-1, 28**2)`. Have you tried that?

Comment: 28*28 == 784.  So you can reshape the (64,28,28) array to (64,784).  That array would `dot` with the (784,50) producing a (64,50) array.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Your answers really helped me to fix this problem!